# Is there a selector that looks a the content of table td and decides to apply backcolor red, for instance, if the td contains "$-", a negative number

Tags: css

Is there a selector that looks a the content of table td and decides to apply backgoundcolor red, for instance, if the td contains "$-", i.e. a negative number
being dataframe my table type, I tried

```
.dataframe td:contains("-") {
    background-color: red;
}
```

but it fails to work.

Comment: No, not in CSS. You'd need JavaScript.

Comment: No. CSS is not content aware.